# Concrete Mathematics: Why replace floor of x with a sum is correct?

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In the Concrete Mathematics book, the solution for the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{a^2-1}\lfloor \sqrt k \rfloor$ is written as follows.

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{0 \le k < a^2} \lfloor \sqrt k \rfloor
&= \sum_{j, k} [1 \le j \le \sqrt k][0 \le k < a^2]\\
&= \sum_{1 \le j < a} \sum_k [j^2 \le k < a^2]\\
&= \sum (a^2 - j^2) = a^3 - \frac{1}{3}a(a + \frac{1}{2})(a + 1), \text{integer a}
\end{align*}
$$

What I don't understand is the first step. How can $\lfloor \sqrt k \rfloor$ be equal to $\sum_j [1 \le j \le \sqrt k]$ ?

Comment: I reckon that should be $\sum_{0\le k<a^2}\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor=\cdots$. I mean what is the point of writing $\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor$ if you know $k$ is always going to be an integer?

Comment: my bad, mistyped the question. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x>0$ and consider
$S=\sum_j[1\le j\le x]$.
This is the sum of $[1\le j\le x]$ over all integers $j$.
Now, $[1\le j\le x]$ equals $1$ whenever $1\le j\le x$ and zero otherwise.
So $S$ is the number of integers $j$ with $1\le j\le x$. These integers
are $1,\ldots,\lfloor x\rfloor$. There are $\lfloor x\rfloor$ of them:
$S=\lfloor x\rfloor$.